# How can I display a mapped class from MongoDB including the extra elements in a TreeView?

Tags: c#, winforms, mongodb, treeview

I have a class that I map to a MongoDB document that represents entries from a vehicle reflash. For reference, here is what the class looks like:

```
public class VehicleEntry
{
    [BsonElement("@Date")]
    [BsonDefaultValue("")]
    public String Date { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("@Vin")]
    [BsonDefaultValue("")]
    public String Vin { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("PostFlashDTCs")]
    [BsonDefaultValue("0")]
    public String PostFlashDTCs { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("PreFlashDTCs")]
    [BsonDefaultValue("0")]
    public String PreFlashDTCs { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("UserName")]
    [BsonDefaultValue("")]
    public String UserName { get; set; }

    [BsonExtraElements]
    public BsonDocument ExtraElements { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to display this in a TreeView, but am struggling because I have to consider multiple element types as well as an uncertain amount of nesting (which is why I believe a TreeView is good here). I'm certain that this will require recursion, but I'm not sure how to use it and loop through properties.

---

I am self-answering this question to help any future users who stumble upon it, but am of course open to suggestions or alternative methods.

Answer (score 0):

The Reflection namespace can be used to iterate over the individual properties in the VehicleEntry object. Let's say that each VehicleEntry is its own node with that as the title, we can loop through like this:

```
private void DisplayVehiclesForTreeView(List<VehicleEntry> vehicles)
{
    // Loop through each vehicle
    foreach (VehicleEntry vehicle in vehicles)
    {
        // Make node by VehicleEntry
        TreeNode vehNode = new TreeNode("VehicleEntry");

        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in vehicle.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (propertyInfo.CanRead)
            {
                object val = propertyInfo.GetValue(vehicle, null);
                if (val is string)
                {
                    vehNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(propertyInfo.Name + ": " + val));
                }
                else if (val is BsonDocument)
                {
                    vehNode.Nodes.Add(GetNodeForDocument((BsonDocument)val, propertyInfo.Name));
                }
            }
        }

        // Add node to tree view
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(vehNode);
    }
}
```

Note that since our class only has strings and the extra BsonElements object, we can just have two if statements for those types. This may change in the future. Also, each node that is a string will be displayed by property and value, such as `Vin: abcdefg123456`. Then, when it gets to our defined ExtraElements from the BsonDocument, it goes to a recursive method:

```
private TreeNode GetTreeNodeFromDocument(String rootName, BsonDocument document)
{
    TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode(rootName);

    // Loop through each element in the document
    foreach (BsonElement element in document.Elements)
    {
        // Switch based on type
        switch (element.Value.BsonType)
        {
            // If it's just a string, add it by name.
            case BsonType.String:
                rootNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(element.Name + ": " + element.Value.ToString()));
                break;
            // If it's a document, recurse again.
            case BsonType.Document:
                rootNode.Nodes.Add(GetTreeNodeFromDocument(element.Name, element.Value.AsBsonDocument));
                break;
            // If it's an array, loop with recursion
            case BsonType.Array:
                foreach (BsonDocument arrayDocument in element.Value.AsBsonArray)
                {
                    rootNode.Nodes.Add(GetTreeNodeFromDocument(element.Name, arrayDocument));
                }
                break;
            // Handles all cases for this application so far.
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    return rootNode;
}
```

Another situation that we know is exclusive to this case is that the document will have strings, nested documents, or arrays, and we handle each case appropriately. Strings are displayed the same as the others, and documents and array documents are iterated through recursively and all break down to a string in the end. Below is a screenshot of what this looks like.

[image]